# ES6 import class causes circular dependency

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, circular-dependency

Currently, I'm struggling with **circular dependency condition**. Let's say I have two classes in two different `JS` files that need each other.

First (`Popup.js`):

```
import App from "./App";

export default class Popup {
  onAppend() {
    App.instance.putLayer(this._dom, App.LAYERS.POPUP); // This needs to call a static variable from App class
  }
}
```

Second (`App.js`):

```
import Popup from "./Popup";

export default class App {
  someMethod() {
    ...
    Popup.close(); // This needs to call a static method from Popup class
  }
}
```

But, `ESLint` always shows me a `dependency cycle detected` warning. How to solve this?

Comment: It's a warning. The code works fine.

Comment: Is there any best practice to avoid it?

Comment: Just to clarify on Bergi's comment. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't. I wouldn't take it for granted. I have stumbled upon this problem myself when working with React and sometimes involved components would throw errors because of initialization order. I'm interested too in reading about a solution.

Comment: @JustinusHermawan Just put them in the same file, or don't use static methods but put them on different objects, or use dependency injection. There are many ways

Comment: @Bergi I think injecting the `App`'s singleton instance to the `Popup` and other components' constructor is a good idea.